# Do you clean the data before calculating MASE (Mean Absolute Scaled Error)

Tags: forecasting, data-imputation, data-preprocessing, mase

The denominator in the MASE calculation for seasonal data is the MAE of the seasonal naive forecast calculated in-sample.

Is it common to do imputation before calculating the seasonal naive MAE or do you calculate the seasonal naive MAE with no data cleaning? Would I apply the same imputation I would normally apply if I were trying to use the seasonal naive as an actual forecast? This would include things like imputing missing values. Or would I leave missing values as NA?

Comment: Do the missing values make it into your model?

Comment: Yes, and this is the main concern for me. Does it make more sense for the in-sample denominator in the MASE calculation to be more like a real forecast where we would impute those missing values so they do not mess up the forecast, or do we just bit the bullet and remove those values when they are missing from the actual and the forecasted values. I am thinking that we do want to impute those values. If I leave them as NA then I would be removing a lot of data which would otherwise have to have been forecasted in an out-of-sample situation.

Comment: Have you or have you not settled how you’re going to handle the missing data?

Comment: No, some likely choices are exponential smoothing, a seasonal naive method or, previous medians.